# python 3.3.1 try to solve if else condition

Tags: python-3.3

i am newbie in learning python 3 and have ask for helps
code :

```
movies = ["holy grail",1975,"terry jones",91
  [ "gramham chamman",
    ["michael palin","john crees","eric idle","terry jones"]]]
        for each_item in movies:
if isinstance (each_item,list):
    for nested_item in each_item :
        print (nested_item)
                    else:
                    print (each_item)



# when i type the next line with  " else : " 
  the program (python shell) told me syntax error
```

i do not know how to solve it
thank you very much

Comment: you should check your indents first. There is wrong indent in first for-if and last else-print. So correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
movies = ["holy grail",1975,"terry jones",91,[ "gramham chamman",
    ["michael palin","john crees","eric idle","terry jones"]]]
for each_item in movies:
    if isinstance (each_item,list):
        for nested_item in each_item :
            print (nested_item)
    else:
        print (each_item)
```

Changes were

1. adding a `,` after 91. `91["..."` isn't legal, ints aren't subscriptable.
2. apply proper indentation. indentation is **significant** in python, you need to be careful! Improperly indented code can/will behave very differently to what you where expecting.

Produces:

```
>>> 
holy grail
1975
terry jones
91
gramham chamman
['michael palin', 'john crees', 'eric idle', 'terry jones']
```